# What is the correct way to connect to a MariaDB/MySQL server in a long running multithreaded C program?

Tags: mysql, c, multithreading, mariadb, thread-safety

After reading the docs it's still unclear to me what the correct usage is. Should one:

1. Call `mysql_init()` and `mysql_real_connect()` once at startup, before thread creation, and all threads share the `MYSQL` handle returned from `mysql_real_connect()`.
2. Call `mysql_init()` once at startup, before thread creation, and then each thread calls `mysql_real_connect()` to get a thread specific `MYSQL` handle.
3. Each thread calls `mysql_init()` and `mysql_real_connect()`.
4. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sharing a connection over multiple threads is not a good idea, since you have to handle all kind of problems in your application: Transaction safety, protocol buffers etc.
2. `mysql_init()` API function initializes a connection handle (`MYSQL`) which will be used to connect to a server via `mysql_real_connect()`. Trying to connect with the same handle again will result in an error (CR_ALREADY_CONNECTED=2058).
3. Using one connection per thread is the better solution. If threads don't use the connection all the time, use a connection pool (e.g. by using Connector/C++).